# Meaning of: "В кого он такой пошёл?"

Tags: словоупотребление

I pride myself on not bringing stupid questions here, and I feel silly because I know what all the words in this question mean. I just can't make any sense of them. Is there a productive pattern here that I should know?

> "В кого он такой пошёл?"

Then I saw this:

> Ну и гнилой народ теперь пошёл!

Is it similar in meaning? The pattern looks the same.

Comment: Semantically, there is a significant difference. *В кого они такие **пошли**, в отца? Да, стали **похожими** на отца.* (Походили — стали похожими) | Сигареты нынче *дорогие* пошли? Да, стали *дорогими*.  | Времена пошли нынче *трудные?* Да, стали *трудными.* | Клиент косяками пошел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to the other answers. The phrase

> Ну и гнилой народ теперь пошёл!

is another idiom: "  теперь пошел" (is usually used to describe group of people or things) means changing its characteristics. Here it means:

> People have become bad (literally "rotten", it could mean many negative characteristics).

This idiom means changing, not inheritance. Also, it's often used in the singular instead of the plural:

> Студент теперь ленивый пошел

which translates to "students have become (so) lazy" or even "all students have become (so) lazy."

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry - I love patterns :)  So if I understood you correctly, this is a general statement about how people have become? For example, "Students have become so lazy!" meaning <I can't believe how lazy students are these days!> Am I right?

Comment: @CocoPop Yes, you are right, but you can say this about animals or things, not only about people.

Comment: So just to test the pattern, could you use it to say that cigarettes have gotten expensive?

Comment: @CocoPop Yes, no problem.

Comment: *ну и дорогие нынче сигареты пошли* = *well, the cigarettes have gotten rather/so expensive these days*

Answer (score 10):

`Пойти в кого-то` is an idiom that means inheriting some personal traits from ancestors. For me it's difficult to translate your phrase without a context, namely, what qualities are implied. I can imagine something like `Он очень умный. В кого он такой пошёл?`. This is translated as "He's very smart. Whom did he inherit this from?". However, it sounds quite formal, whereas `пойти в кого-то` is informal in Russian. Probably, there's some similar idiom in English.

Comment: Yes!  "Who does he take after?" meaning is he like his father or someone else in his family that has the same quality, look or talent. Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: @CocoPop - in Russian, "в кого он такой пошёл" is mostly about **negative** qualities or behaviour.

Comment: @user31264, I woudn't agree with you. From my experience, it is used almost equally often for positive and negative qualities.

Comment: @Ivan, from the first 3 google pages, there are 20 negatives, 5 positives, others are doubles or unclear.

Comment: @user31264, no, it's clearly very negative. "в кого он пошёл" is on the other hand quite neutral.

Answer (score -3):

There is so many meanings for Russian idioms with the word `выйти`, for example
`выйти замуж`
`выйти в деда/отца`
`выйти на пенсию`
`выйти во вред/ущерб`
`не выйти лицом`
`выйти по-твоему`
`...`
that it is worth looking into a page where they were collected in block — [frazeologiya.ru](http://www.frazeologiya.ru/fraza/vyiyti.htm)

Note that a questions may arise about words in past/future tense, participle, and so on, but in the dictionary frazeologiya.ru you should searhing for Infinitive.

An infinitive then can be used again, in the [ruscorpora.ru](http://ruscorpora.ru/en/search-main.html), filling forms, word by word, in the each firsts text filds in the form. The example from OP
`В кого он такой пошёл?`
should be set as shown below:

[image]

Remembering that an order of words in Russian phrase may be changed, it is easily understood that we can try searching
`в`
`кто`
`выйти`
For the word `кто` we can add the property *accusative* that tightens search criteria.
For the verb `выйти` there is also a perfective aspect that point out at the start of the act: `пойти`.

Comment: Thank you, Avtokod, but what does выйти have to do with this expression?

Comment: @CocoPop , you don't need any living person to understand this. Every idioms implies literally decoding, because a root of a word is everyday Russian root. E.g. `Выйти` is literally to leave something. `Выйти в отца`— the spirit of you leave your body and enter to father's body. Then we have an image of the father, with all his habits. `Выйти в люди` — you situated inside the crowd of the poor people. You leave this crowd and enter to the circle of elite (people of high station, wealth). I gave these instructions to solve the idioms of Russian yourself.

Comment: @CocoPop , `Выйти за пределы` — to go beyond the bounds. `Вышел` — now to be outside of the bounds. ~~~~~~ `Выйти на пенсию`. A man has made a shift — `он вышел` — from a state of employability to a new level of life, retirement age. The same, related to *a state*, is relevant to `Выйти из положения, выйти на инвалидность, выйти в отставку, выйти в жизнь, выйти замуж, выйти из боя, выйти из моды, выйти из роли, выйти из ума, выйти из пелёнок...` Am I making sense?

Comment: @CocoPop , The preposition `на`=`on` |~~~~| `Выйти на связь` — to be on communication line, to sit like a bird on an aerial line — to be on-line. `Будь на связи!` — be on-line! The same is relevant to `выйти на старт, выйти на орбиту, выйти на рубеж`

Comment: @CocoPop , The preposition `в`=`into`. `Выйти в эфир` — `эфир` is the gas like the Air, but we say for that `выйти на воздух`, to relax in the fresh air, implying that there are no borders. So `выйти в эфир` — literally — to go into a new volume filled with gas (ether), now to be inside this volume. The same is relevant to `Выйти в свет, выйти в тыл, выйти в тираж`. There is only couple the very idiom like `(Вот какая) петрушка вышла`. Are we on the same page?

Comment: @Avtokod: that's a great theory you have, analyzing idioms. Could you please help me with one? It literally means "to be like a snowman in the open".

Comment: @Quassnoi , Has it something to do with the Russian word `выйти`?

Comment: @Avtokod: no it doesn't. However, if you suggest that "you don't need any living person to understand this" and "every idioms implies literally decoding", you might have no trouble decoding this one.

Comment: @Quassnoi , it decontextualize my explanation. `Выйти-пойти-уйти-зайти-отойти-войти-...` are so common in everyday Russian, that without completely and careful consideration of a large number of usage we definitely have a trouble with the Russian )) How a foreigner would be making a decision? Wonder why does [something] sound just fine for native speakers? Or may prefer approach based on the objective rules without subjective opinions?

Comment: @Avtokod: let me put it really simply: your answer and your comments are vivid illustration on the term "logorrhea", or "excessive flow of words lacking sense". The OP didn't ask for some ridiculous expatiations involving spirit transmigration or ether filling volumes; they asked a very direct question which can be answered with a simple five-word English phrase. It's at least disrespectful to answer a question about a language idiom from a non-native speaker with an offer to deduce the meaning.

Comment: @Avtokod: I really appreciate all the time and effort you put into your answer(s), but I just didn't get what you were trying to tell me. I'm afraid I missed your point.

Comment: @CocoPop  I am assuming that you do encounter problems in following sentence `Под старость опять начинает походить на того, на кого походил ребенком. [К. Д. Ушинский. О народности в общественном воспитании (1856)]`

Comment: "In his old age he started to take after the one he took after as a child" ?

Comment: @CocoPop ,  You are right and I am delighted. And if I were an alien in English, what would I do? The reverse process:  "In his old age he started to take [take the form of the one, to form a mental picture to others] after the one he took [he took the form of a ...] after as a child" (I stand to be corrected, English is not my native language) — So, an Englishman, Frenchman, Russian man, ... has tackled the same challenge in a foreigner linguistic framework.